# Cannot find property 'value' undefined

Tags: javascript

This is my code snippet and i am getting the same error of property undefined. Please help me to solve this problem.I tried doing getElementsByName and Id but then also it is not giving me proper output.

```
<script>
        function Check(){

            try{
                var txtfname=$('#txtFirstName')[0].value;
                var txtlname=$('txtLastName')[1].value;
                var txtcontact=$('txtContact')[2].value;

                var regex=/^[A-Za-z]*$/;
                var regex1=/^[0-9]{10}$/;

                if(!txtfname.length>0){
                    $('#txtFirstName').addClass('error');
                    $('#txtFirstName')[0].title="Please enter valid name";


                    /*$('#txtFirstName').focus();
                    $('#txtLastName').focus();
                    $('#txtContact').focus();*/
                    return false;
                }else{
                    if(!regex.test(txtfname)){
                        $('#txtFirstName').addClass('error');
                        $('#txtFirstName')[0].title="Please enter valid name";
                    }/*else{
                        $('#txtFirstName').removeClass('error');
                        return true;
                    }*/
                }
                if(!txtlname.length>0){
                    $('txtLastName').addClass('error');
                    $('txtLastName')[1].title="Please enter valid name";
                    return false;
                }else{
                    if(!regex.test(txtlname)){
                        $('txtLastName').addClass('error');
                        $('txtLastName')[1].title="Please enter valid name";
                    }/*else{
                        $('txtLastName').removeClass('error');
                        return true;
                    }*/
                }
                if(!txtcontact.length>0){
                    $('txtContact').addClass('error');
                    $('txtContact')[2].title="Please enter valid contact number";
                    return false;
                }else{
                    if(!regex1.test(txtcontact)){
                        $('txtContact').addClass('error');
                        $('txtContact')[2].title="Please enter valid contact number";
                    }else{
                        $('txtContact').removeClass('error');
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                /*else{

                    if(!regex.test(txtfname)){
                        $('#txtFirstName').addClass('error');
                        $('#txtFirstName')[0].title="Please enter valid name";
                        $('#txtLastName').addClass('error');
                        $('#txtLastName')[1].title="Please enter valid name";
                    }else {
                        $('#txtFirstName').removeClass('error');
                        $('#txtLastName').removeClass('error');
                        return true;
                    }
                    if(!regex1.test(txtcontact)){
                        $('txtContact').addClass('error');
                        $('#txtContact')[2].title="Please enter valid contact number";
                    }else{
                        $('#txtContact').removeClass('error');
                        return true;
                    }
                }*/
            }catch(error){
                alert(error);
            }
        }


    </script>
```

Comment: on which line or on which code you are getting. Please specify.

Comment: Please post your html code.. for more Details

Comment: `var txtlname=$('txtLastName')[1].value;` & `var txtcontact=$('txtContact')[2].value;` . Missing `#` in your selector?

Comment: Doing `$('txtLastName')` will return `[]` empty HTMLCollection. If `txtLastName` is a class, then it should be `$('.txtLastName')` and if its is ID, then `$('#txtLastName')`. Also try to keep unique ids to elements.

Comment: You can always upvote the answers that helped you. People took time to answer a question of yours, you see. If it helps, just upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the selector expression `$('#txtFirstName')` is equivalent to `document.getElementById('txtFirstName')` .So using index later on i.e. `$('#txtFirstName')[0]` will not yield you any result i.e. it is **undefined**. Use indexer if you are going for 'class' selector (.)

That's why you function will be breaking on the first line itself.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery selectors works only if you define the element properly. When you write `$('txtLastName').addClass('error');` it has no meaning and will result an empty object which is **undefined** because you don't have any class (.) or id (#) selectors defined. The proper way is:

```
$('#txtLastName').addClass('error'); // for id
$('.txtLastName').addClass('error'); // for class
```

And you cannot get the value by `.value` from input elements. You should use `.val()` instead. By fixing two of your mistakes at once, see the difference between these two.

var txtcontact = $('txtContact')[2].value;
var txtcontact = $('.txtContact')[2].val();

Also, instead of selecting a class with an index (it makes only sense when you use index selectors with a class), you should use a different id for each of your elements. You can add prefixes or suffixes to your id or class definitions in order to make them more readable. Take a look:

Instead of indexes like:

```
var txtcontact = $('.txtContact')[0].val();
```

You could use

```
var txtcontact = $('#txtContact').val();
var txtcontactEdit = $('#txtContactEdit').val();
```

Fix these, and your code will run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any other javascript? Have you tried wrapping your code in a DOM ready function? You might need to wait for certain elements to be loaded otherwise it will throw errors.

```
$(function() {
    ... 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var txtfname=$('#txtFirstName')[0].value;
var txtlname=$('txtLastName')[1].value;
var txtcontact=$('txtContact')[2].value;
```

In the second and third line here you are attempting to select tag types instead of IDs.

Assuming you are instead intending to do:

```
var txtlname=$('#txtLastName').val();
var txtcontact=$('#txtContact').val();
```

Note that I am using jQuery's [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function, which is the jQuery-ish way to get a form element's value.

You should also cache your jQuery selectors, since you use them again in your code. By that, I mean declaring a var to the jQuery function:

```
var $txtFirstName = $('#txtFirstName');
```

and then later in the function:

```
$txtFirstName.val() // <-- doesn't re-run the selector
```